# Error with queryset get_absolute_urls Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'detail' with keyword arguments '{'slug': 'test'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['detail<slug:slug/\\Z']
```

I'm trying to create a product detail, filtering it by slug(maybe it can be ID), so I decided to send the slug trough an URL and then filter the product by the specifiedslug, but im getting troubles to implement it(my other get_absolute_url its working but this one I cant fix).

models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=False, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=False)
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(
        SubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    short_description = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, unique=False, blank=True, null=True)
    long_description = models.TextField(unique=False, blank=True, null=False)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, unique=False)
    on_promotion = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("product:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('detail<slug:slug/', views.ProductDetail.as_view(), name="detail"),

    path('category-<int:category_id>/', views.category, name="category"),
    path('category-<int:category_id>/subcategory-<int:subcategory_id>',
         views.subcategory, name="subcategory")
]
```

views.py
"""

```
def detail(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(product_id)
    return render(request, 'product/detail.html', {'product_id': product})
"""


class ProductDetail(DetailView):
    template_name = 'product/detail.html'
    # queryset = Product.available.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Product.available.filter(slug=self.kwargs.get("slug"))
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

template:

```
<a href="{{product.get_absolute_url}}">aaa</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
path('detail<slug:slug/', views.ProductDetail.as_view(), name="detail"),
```

the path is wrong, you forgot to put the closing **>** after slug

```
'detail<slug:slug>/'
```

and i am not sure whether you wrote **app_name = "product"** or not in urls.py

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove `product:` in the `get_absolute_url` method. If you need to add the app namespace (which you don't for your current case), you should use the `current_app` argument as specified here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/#topics-http-reversing-url-namespaces

In addition to the above, you could also use `{% url 'detail' product.slug %}`

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure about your main `urls.py`, but i know: to use named urls concatenated with ':' you should provide url-namespace.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces

please check in settings - main `urls.py`:

```
path('products', include('products.urls', namespace='products))
```

After that you can use:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("products:detail", current_app=self.request.resolver_match.namespace, kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

In your case you should omit 'product:'

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
   return reverse('detail', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

Comment: ´but why would my other urls work and only this one not?(did'nt work

Comment: @KaynanKaynanFelipeRodrigues  probably you don't close slug tag? path('detail<slug:slug>/'...